# How to filter dataframe columns between two rows that contain specific string in column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, filter

I am trying to understand how to select only those rows in my dataframe that are between two specific rows. These rows contain two specific strings in one of the columns. I will explain further with this example.

I have the following dataframe:

```
       String      Value
-------------------------
 0       Blue         45     
 1        Red         35   
 2      Green         75    
 3      Start         65   
 4     Orange         33   
 5     Purple         65   
 6       Teal         34
 7     Indigo         44
 8        End         32
 9     Yellow         22 
10        Red         14
```

There is only one instance of "Start" and only one instance of "End" in the "String" column. I only want the rows of this dataframe that are between the rows that contain "Start" and "Stop" in the "String" column, and so I want to produce this output dataframe:

```
       String      Value
-------------------------  
 3      Start         65   
 4     Orange         33   
 5     Purple         65   
 6       Teal         34
 7     Indigo         44
 8        End         32
```

Also, I want to preserve the order of those rows I am preserving, and so preserving the order of "Start", "Orange", "Purple", "Teal", "Indigo", "End".

I know I can index these specific columns by doing:

```
index_start = df.index[df['String'] == 'Start']
index_end = df.index[df['String'] == 'End']
```

But I am not sure how to actually filter out all rows that are not between these two strings. How can I accomplish this in python?

Comment: do you have exactly one Start and one Stop? What happens if you have more? Is it always balanced?

Comment: Sorry, important information there I should have clarified. Yes, there is only one instance of "Start", and only one instance of "End".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both values are present you temporarily set "String" as index:

```
df.set_index('String').loc['Start':'End'].reset_index()
```

output:

```
   String  Value
0   Start     65
1  Orange     33
2  Purple     65
3    Teal     34
4  Indigo     44
5     End     32
```

Alternatively, using `isin` (then the order of Start/End doesn't matter):

```
m = df['String'].isin(['Start', 'End']).cumsum().eq(1)
df[m|m.shift()]
```

output:

```
   String  Value
3   Start     65
4  Orange     33
5  Purple     65
6    Teal     34
7  Indigo     44
8     End     32
```

Comment: Thank you! Ah so for your first suggestion, 'df.set_index('String').loc['Start':'End'].reset_index()', order of the rows is preserved correct? I am trying to preserve the order of the rows.

Comment: You always seem to have come across things that I have never seen before; I have never seen `m|m.shift()` to filter a dataframe!

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis the order of the rows with be preserved ;)

Answer (score 3):

This should be enough, iloc[] is useful when you try to locate rows by index, and it works the same as slices in lists.

```
index_start = df.index[df['String'] == 'Start']
index_end = df.index[df['String'] == 'End']  
df.iloc[index_start[0]:index_end[0]+1]
```

More information: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Answer (score 2):

You can build a boolean mask using `eq` + `cummax` and filter:

```
out = df[df['String'].eq('Start').cummax() & df.loc[::-1, 'String'].eq('End').cummax()]
```

Output:

```
   String  Value
3   Start     65
4  Orange     33
5  Purple     65
6    Teal     34
7  Indigo     44
8     End     32
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this suggestion preserve the order of the rows that are preserved?

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis yes, it's boolean indexing, so the index order will stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

As you return the index values through your work:

```
df.iloc[index_start.item(): index_end.item()]
```